# How do i write redis channel layer in django and windows

Tags: django, redis

I have this code in my settings.py, but it seems not working in django and windows, any ideas on how to correct this code? i used redis server backend in my settings make my consumers.py function well

```
async def websocket_receive(self, event):
    print('receive', event)
    front_text = event.get('text', None)
    if front_text is not None:
        loaded_dict_data = json.loads(front_text)
        msg = loaded_dict_data.get('message')
        user = self.scope['user']
        username = 'default'
        if user.is_authenticated:
            username = user.username
        myResponse = {
            'message': msg,
            'username': username
        }
        await self.create_chat_message(user, msg)
        await self.channel_layer.group_send(
            self.chat_room,
            {
                "type": "chat_message",
                "text": json.dumps(myResponse)
            }
        )

async def chat_message(self, event):
    print('message', event)
    await self.send({
        "type": "websocket.send",
        "text": event["text"]
    })
```

this is my settings.py

```
CHANNEL_LAYERS = {
    'default':
        { 'BACKEND': 'channels_redis.core.RedisChannelLayer',
          'CONFIG':{
              "hosts": [('127.0.0.1', 6379)],
          },
        },
}
```

what i have tried

```
CHANNEL_LAYERS = {
    "default": {
        "BACKEND": "channels_redis.core.RedisChannelLayer",
        "CONFIG": {
            "hosts": [("localhost", 6379)],
        },
    },
}
```

Comment: please show the model for `StudentsEnrolledSubject`

Comment: just a sec. mr @ReinstateMonica Monica

Comment: see my update question sir

Comment: I will also need to see `StudentsEnrollmentRecord`

Comment: and probably `StudentUsers`

Comment: i have only 2 fields in StudentsEnrolledSubject, please see my update question

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/208360/discussion-between-zen-and-reinstate-monica).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are selecting the foreign key to `StudentProfile` in your `.values` clause, and not the name field.  To fix this simply add `__Firstname`:

```
students = studentsEnrolledSubjectsGrade.objects.filter(Teacher=teacher).filter(grading_Period=period).filter(
 Subjects=subject).filter(Grading_Categories=category).filter(GradeLevel=grade).order_by(
        'Students_Enrollment_Records', 'Date'
).values('Students_Enrollment_Records__Students_Enrollment_Records__Student_Users__Firstname', 'Date', 'Grade').distinct()
```

Comment: Sorry, this user and the bounty are gone; they were abusing multiple accounts and replaced questions with entirely new ones to try to keep question bans at bay.

Comment: @MartijnPieters thanks for letting me know :-) this would have been quite frustrating otherwise